# Display the return of an ajax in the corresponding row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I needed to add runtime rows on a table and then send data to database. I managed to do most of it however I am stuck on 2 parts of the program.

1. I am using Ajax to check the available quantity from a drop down, which I wish to display in the corresponding row, but cant, I have been able to alert the correct value so far).
2. The php post is sending me one parameter less than is available on the form if I fill any row, but send me the correct amount of parameters if I add rows and don’t fill any information. ( ie if I add 3 blank rows and click on submit it submits 4 values, -> because one row is hidden however if I fill any of the 3 rows in the screen it sends as parameter only 3 post for $name)

```js
function getSpQty(strURL) {
  var xmlhttp;
  console.log(this)
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {

      if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

        document.getElementById('sp').value = xmlhttp.responseText;

      } else {
        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + xmlhttp.statusText);
      }
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", strURL, true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

```html
<?php include_once( "dbConn-SP.php"); $sqlSP="select * from dbo.SparepartManagement" ; $stmtSP=s qlsrv_query($connIgms, $sqlSP); ?>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="js/jquery1.7.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var id = 0;
      // Add button functionality
      $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
        id++;
        var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");
        // Get a new row based on the prototype row
        var prot = master.find(".prototype").clone();
        prot.attr("class", "")
        prot.find(".id").attr("value", id);
        master.find("tbody").append(prot);
      });
      // Remove button functionality
      $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .dynatable {
      border: solid 1px #000;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    .dynatable th,
    .dynatable td {
      border: solid 1px #000;
      padding: 2px 10px;
      width: 170px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .dynatable .prototype {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2" src="spQty.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="test.php" method="post" name="frm">
    <table width="100%" class="dynatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="144">ID</th>
          <th width="144">Spareparts</th>
          <th width="144">Quanitity</th>
          <th width="144">Issued Quantity</th>
          <th width="140">
            <button type="button" class="add">Add</button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="prototype">
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="id[]" value="0" class="id" />
          </td>

          <td>
            <select style="width:200px" name="name[]" id="sp" onChange="getSpQty('SPName.php?spareparts='+this.value)">
              <option value="error">Select Spare Parts</option>
              <?php while($viewAllSP=s qlsrv_fetch_array($stmtSP,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { echo "<option value='$viewAllSP[GeneralItemDescription]'>$viewAllSP[GeneralItemDescription]</option>\n"; }; ?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="col4[]" value="" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="col3[]" value="" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <button class="remove">Remove</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value='send' />
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the SPName.php

```
include_once("dbConn-SP.php");

$spareparts=$_REQUEST['spareparts'];


$tsqls = "select InitialQty from SparepartManagement where GeneralItemDescription ='$spareparts'";




    $params = array();
    $options =  array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connIgms, $tsqls , $params, $options);

    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);




        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
               $test = $row['InitialQty'];


            }



echo $test; 

?>
```

here is test.php

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(0);

include_once("dbConn-SP.php");

$Qty = $_POST["col4"];
$IssuedQty = $_POST["col3"];
$name= $_POST["name"];
//Step 3: Insert statment
print_r($name);
for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($Qty); $i++) {     
            $j=$i-1;
$Insert = "INSERT INTO SparepartTransaction (SPDesc,InitialQty,QtyIssued) Values ".
            " ('$name[$j]','$Qty[$i]','$IssuedQty[$i]')";   
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connIgms,$Insert);            

            }
sqlsrv_close($connIgms);
?>
```

unfortunately i do not have enough reputation to post a image here so here is a link with the actual display on my screen
http://prntscr.com/749n4n

what i want is that instead of having an alert as -> alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
i wish this value to be displayed on the cell beside the drop down. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you are using jQuery - `<script src="js/jquery1.7.js">` - why are you using `new XMLHttpRequest()`/`new ActiveXObject()` instead of `$.ajax()`?

Comment: if you are using jQuery, you should be able to use the `.html()` function and place the response inside a `div` or `span` or what-have-you.

Comment: in your code sample here you have 1 `<select name="name[]" id="sp">` but it your image it looks like you have 3 selects. Do they all have `id="sp"`? If so, `document.getElementById('sp').value = xmlhttp.responseText;` will not work properly as `id`s are to be unique, and so which of the 3 should this find?

Comment: yes when we click add i tried to find an online solution where i got this piece of code, it clone the hidden row and makes a new one. yh i guess the id=sp is being replicated, i am stuck with this. i have been able to alert the correct value, i tried to integrate jquery to this however i am not being able to. as onchage would stop to work. the function getSpQty is in an external js file.